# Start Zsh with 'Custom Options'

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I've got a couple flags in my zsh configuration - and I've been trying to figure out a way to startup a new shell with them set, but haven't found a solution yet. Any suggestions? For example, I'm looking to do something like:

```
zsh --login --export=RC_BOOTSTRAP:true,RC_DEBUG:true
```

**Edit 01**

Essentially, I'm trying to setup custom shell options. The best method I've come up with so far is:

```
# set the flags as environment variables and restart the shell
exec env RC_BOOTSTRAP=true RC_DEBUG=true zsh --login
```

And in my startup files, I have:

```
# I don't want these flags to propagate into additional shells
# so they need to be 'unexported'
RC_TMP_BOOTSTRAP=${RC_BOOTSTRAP:-false} && unset RC_BOOTSTRAP
RC_BOOTSTRAP=${RC_TMP_BOOTSTRAP} && unset RC_TMP_BOOTSTRAP
RC_TMP_DEBUG=${RC_DEBUG:-false} && unset RC_DEBUG
RC_DEBUG=${RC_TMP_DEBUG} && unset RC_TMP_DEBUG
```

This *works*, but it's pretty ugly. Any suggestions?

**Edit 02**
Based on the solution by @gilbert:

```
exec env RC_FLAGS='RC_BOOTSTRAP=true RC_LOG_LEVEL=4' zsh --login
[[ -n $RC_FLAGS ]] && { eval "$RC_FLAGS"; unset RC_FLAGS; }
```

Comment: Do you have a .zshrc file?

Comment: Of course. My rcfiles do some things based on flags. Currently, I've got a local configuration, where I set the flag values (bootstrap, debug, etc). I'm looking for a more convenient way to restart the current shell (`exec zsh --login`) and set the flag at the same time, rather than having to edit the flag in the configuration file and then restart the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your temporary variables aren't necessary:

```
: ${RC_BOOTSTRAP:=false}
: ${RC_DEBUG:=false}
# Unexport them
declare +x RC_BOOTSTRAP RC_DEBUG
```

The first two lines, by the way, are not unique to `zsh`; they would work in any POSIX-compatible shell. Each variable, if not already present in the environment, is set to `false`.

Starting the shell with these variables doesn't necessarily require `env`:

```
RC_BOOTSTRAP=true RC_DEBUG=true exec zsh --login
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit uglier in syntax, but fewer lines:

```
exec env eval_preset='RC_BOOTSTRAP=true;RC_DEBUG=true' zsh --login
```

And in the startup file:

```
eval "${eval_preset:-true}"; unset eval_preset
```

Beware, I haven't actually run these so I leave debugging to the student.